# How can you customize all elements in a table header?

Tags: vuetify.js

Looking at the examples on [this page](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#customizing-default-header), what is the way to apply toUpper to all header items? It looks too clumsy having to do it one-by-one (i.e. header.calories, header.fat...) and I can't figure out how a v-for can wrap around the template/v-slot element. Is the only way to use a 'div' and flex it horizontally?

```
 <template>
   <v-data-table
     :headers="headers"
     :items="desserts"
     class="elevation-1"
   >
     <template v-slot:header.name="{ header }">
       {{ header.text.toUpperCase() }}
     </template>
   </v-data-table>
 </template>

 <script>
   export default {
     data: () => ({
       headers: [
         {
           text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
           align: 'start',
           value: 'name',
         },
         { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
         { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
         { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
         { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
         { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
       ],
       desserts: [
         {
           name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
           calories: 159,
           fat: 6.0,
           carbs: 24,
           protein: 4.0,
           iron: '1%',
         },
         ....// rest of it
       ],
     }),
   }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to loop the headers to make all capitalize

here is the working codepen: https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/gOaRWQb?editors=1010

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      class="elevation-1"
      hide-default-header
    >
      <template v-slot:header="{ props }">
        <th v-for="head in props.headers">{{ head.text.toUpperCase() }}
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    headers: [
      {
        text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
        align: 'start',
        value: 'name',
      },
      { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
      { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
      { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
      { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
      { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
    ],
    desserts: [
      {
        name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
        calories: 159,
        fat: 6.0,
        carbs: 24,
        protein: 4.0,
        iron: '1%',
      },
      {
        name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
        calories: 237,
        fat: 9.0,
        carbs: 37,
        protein: 4.3,
        iron: '1%',
      },
      {
        name: 'Eclair',
        calories: 262,
        fat: 16.0,
        carbs: 23,
        protein: 6.0,
        iron: '7%',
      },
      {
        name: 'Cupcake',
        calories: 305,
        fat: 3.7,
        carbs: 67,
        protein: 4.3,
        iron: '8%',
      },
      {
        name: 'Gingerbread',
        calories: 356,
        fat: 16.0,
        carbs: 49,
        protein: 3.9,
        iron: '16%',
      },
      {
        name: 'Jelly bean',
        calories: 375,
        fat: 0.0,
        carbs: 94,
        protein: 0.0,
        iron: '0%',
      },
      {
        name: 'Lollipop',
        calories: 392,
        fat: 0.2,
        carbs: 98,
        protein: 0,
        iron: '2%',
      },
      {
        name: 'Honeycomb',
        calories: 408,
        fat: 3.2,
        carbs: 87,
        protein: 6.5,
        iron: '45%',
      },
      {
        name: 'Donut',
        calories: 452,
        fat: 25.0,
        carbs: 51,
        protein: 4.9,
        iron: '22%',
      },
      {
        name: 'KitKat',
        calories: 518,
        fat: 26.0,
        carbs: 65,
        protein: 7,
        iron: '6%',
      },
    ],
  }),
})
```

Comment: Does this affect any of the tables built in functionality?

Comment: No it will work as expected, it is in built in Vuetify, but you have used to override for only one column, I my code, I have made a loop for the same

Comment: It does effect functionality. With this solution you can not use the built-in sorting functionality by each header column

Comment: It also affects the "show-select" functionality. The header checkbox won't be displayed.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest thing would just be to use custom CSS on your component. In the `<style>` section add:

```html
<style>
.v-data-table-header th {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
</style>
```

However, if you need to do more extensive customization on the headers, you can replace the entire header row like this:

```html
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  hide-default-header
>
  <template #header="{ props: { headers } }">
    <thead class="v-data-table-header">
      <tr>
        <th
          v-for="header in headers"
          :key="header.value"
          class="text-uppercase"
          scope="col"
        >
          {{ header.text }}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

**BUT, I would discourage this** because you'll lose the built-in sorting functionality that Vuetify provides. That said, you CAN use this to add an **additional** header row that will appear **before** the default one. Just leave off the `hide-default-header` attribute on the `v-data-table` component and you will get two header rows, one with all of Vuetify's default functionality plus another custom one of your own design.

Answer (score 5):

your code is correct but in this form you need to add each header alone like this:

```
<template>
     <v-data-table
         :headers="headers"
         :items="desserts"
         class="elevation-1"
     >
         <template v-slot:header.name="{ header }">
             {{ header.text.toUpperCase() }}
         </template>

         <template v-slot:header.calories="{ header }">
             {{ header.text.toUpperCase() }}
         </template>
         ...
     </v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: () => ({
            headers: [
     {
       text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
       align: 'start',
       value: 'name',
     },
     { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
     { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
     { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
     { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
     { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
   ],
   desserts: [
     {
       name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
       calories: 159,
       fat: 6.0,
       carbs: 24,
       protein: 4.0,
       iron: '1%',
     },
     ....// rest of it
   ],
 }),
  }
</script>
```

this way you need to do this to every header alone the way of doing it is by adding `v-slot:header.<value from headers array in the data>`

example:

```
headers = [
    {
        text: "text1",
        ...
        value: "category"
    }
]
```

code will be:

```
<template v-slot:header.category="{ header }">
    {{ header.text.toUpperCase() }}
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

First answer is correct, But I want to suggest a little improvement so you don't have to style it manually.

```
<template v-slot:header="{ props }">
    <thead class="v-data-table-header">
        <tr>
            <th v-for="header in props.headers" :key="header.text">{{ header.text }} </th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

3rd answer is supported for vue2. So I just want to suggest a single header approach for data table in vue3.

```js
<template>
  <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="desserts">
    <template v-slot:[`header.name`]="{ column }">
      {{ column.title.toUpperCase() }}
    </template>
    <template v-slot:[`header.calories`]="{ column }">
      {{ column.title.toUpperCase() }}
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>

  < script >
export default {
  data: () => ({
    headers: [
      {
        title: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
        align: 'start',
        value: 'name'
      },
      { title: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
      { title: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
      { title: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
      { title: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
      { title: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' }
    ],
    desserts: [
      {
        name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
        calories: 159,
        fat: 6.0,
        carbs: 24,
        protein: 4.0,
        iron: '1%'
      }
    ]
  })
}
</script>
```