# How can you customize single table header - vue2 -vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, vtable

I've read this answer: [How can you customize all elements in a table header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61466259/how-can-you-customize-all-elements-in-a-table-header)

But it is about all the headers, i just need to add icon to the first header

I've tried to adjust all the headers, but it looks odd, and not clean.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer in the [Vuetify documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#header) but you could also find it in one of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71009634/10961947) from the question you read.

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="items"
>
  <template v-slot:header.HEADER_VALUE="{ header }">
    <!-- ICON HERE -->
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

All you have to do is change the **HEADER_VALUE** to the first header value property and in the template, you just have to put the HTML to show your icon (I guess you will surely use [v-icon](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/icons/)) and it should fix your problem.
Good luck with your project!